# How does extglob work with shell parameter expansion?

Tags: bash, pattern-matching, ksh, prefix, suffix

I thought I understood the use of the optional  **`?(pattern-list)`** in [**`bash`**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) (when **`extglob`** shell option is on) and by default in [**`ksh`**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ksh). For example in `bash`:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ V=35xAB
$ echo "${V#?(35|88)x}" "${V#35}"
AB xAB
```

But when the **matching prefix pattern** is just one `?()` or one `*()`, which introduce what I call **optional patterns**, the `35` is not omitted unless **`##`** is used:

```
$ echo "${V#?(35|88)}" "${V#*(35|88)}"    # Why 35 is not left out?
35xA 35xA
$ echo "${V##?(35|88)}" "${V##*(35|88)}"  # Why is it omitted when ## is used?
xA xA
```

The same behaviour is reported when `?()` and `*()` are used in a **matching suffix pattern** (using `%` and `%%`):

```
$ echo "${V%5?(xA|Bz)}"                   # 5xA is omitted
3
$ echo "${V%?(xA|Bz)}" "${V%*(xA|Bz)}"    # why xA is not left out?
35xA 35xA
$ echo "${V%%?(xA|Bz)}" "${V%%*(xA|Bz)}"  # xA is omitted when %% is used
35 35
```

I tested this issue in the `bash` releases 3.2.25, 4.1.2 and 4.1.6 and it makes me think that, perhaps, I had not properly understood the actual underlying shell mechanism for matching patterns.

May anybody shed light on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `#` matches the shortest possible occurrence of the pattern. `?()` matches zero or one occurrence and `*()` zero or more of pattern. Therefore `#` will match the 0 and do nothing. Same with `%`. Try it with `+()` and it should work as expected.

Comment: @123, why have you changed the title of this question? The `extglob` option does not exist `ksh`.

Comment: yours made no sense. ksh still uses extendedglob, even if the option does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `@` instead of `?` then it works as expected:

```
$> echo "${V#@(35|88)}"
xAB

$> echo "${V%@(xAB|Bzh)}"
35
```

Similarly behavior of `+` instead of `*`:

```
$> echo "${V#*(35|88)}"
35xAB

$>echo "${V#+(35|88)}"
xAB
```

It is because:

- `?(pattern-list)` # Matches **zero** or one occurrence of the given patterns
- `@(pattern-list)` # Matches **one** of the given patterns

And:

- `*(pattern-list)` # Matches **zero** or more occurrences of the given patterns
- `+(pattern-list)` # Matches **one** or more occurrences of the given patterns

Comment: I think the key part here is that `#` will use the shortest possible match, which in these cases is 0 occurrences.

Comment: Right `#` indeed matches shortest possible match but behavior changes when we use `@` instead of `?` in `extglob`.

Comment: The behaviour doesn't change, it still matches the shortest possible match. Just that `@` needs at least one occurrence.

Comment: `@ needs at least one occurrence.` yes that is what I meant